# Loading a controller method on default controller without reference to the controller in the URL

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Hi I'm developing a CodeIgniter application that gives user their own website.

What I'm trying to accomplish: If a user has an account they have their own subdomain (ex: user.website.com), and the default controller becomes 'user_website', if the website is accessed normally (no subdomain) the default controller is 'website'.

When the user accesses their section I have a method for example called 'test'

So to access that the user would go to: 
user.website.com/user_website/test

What I want to happen is:
user.website.com/test

---

So basically what I'm asking is how can I get codeigniter to if there is a subdomain in use access methods for the controller directly without having to put the controller in the url.

So instead of user.website.com/auth going to the auth controller, it would use an auth method of the user_website controller

If anyone can help me out on how to accomplish this, or point me in the right direction, thanks in advance.

Also here is _remap function from MY_Controller which all my controllers extend.

```
public function _remap($method, $arguments)
    {

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), array_slice($this->uri->rsegments, 2));
        }
        else
        {
            show_404(strtolower(get_class($this)).'/'.$method);
        }

        $this->_load_view();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a route, but what you are asking might be to complex.  I have routes like this

```
$route['(:any)'] = "user_website/$1";
```

so if someone goes to user.website.com/test, it will route them to the controller user_website and call the method test, is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/basecamp-style-subdomains-with-codeigniter/) very handy tutorial from NET TUTS, it should answer most of your questions.